# Javascript PubNub subscribe fails

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I'm getting error subscribing to a channel group. Can't figure out the reason why. Here's the code:

```
var pubnub = new PubNub({
        subscribeKey: subKey,
        publishKey: pubKey
      });

pubnub.addListener({
        status: function(s){
          console.log('status',s);
        },
        message: function(m) {
          var msg = m.message; // The Payload
          console.log('new message',msg);
        },
      });

pubnub.subscribe({
        channelGroups: [viewFinderChannelGroup],
        withPresence: false
      });
```

The result is:
    GET http://ps4.pubnub.com/v2/subscribe/…db1b&uuid=&pnsdk=PubNub-JS-Web%2F4.3.3 400 (Error)

Console output doesn't help much:

```
status Object {error: true, operation: "PNSubscribeOperation", statusCode: 400, errorData: Error: Error
at Request.<anonymous> (https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.3.3.js:1330:…, category: "PNBadRequestCategory"}
```

Answer (score 0):

withPresence doesn't take false. Just remove the wihPresence, it should be good. Try the below code.

```
var pubnub = new PubNub({
        subscribeKey: subKey,
        publishKey: pubKey
      });

pubnub.addListener({
        status: function(s){
          console.log('status',s);
        },
        message: function(m) {
          var msg = m.message; // The Payload
          console.log('new message',msg);
        },
      });

pubnub.subscribe({
        channelGroups: [viewFinderChannelGroup]
      });
```